# How to remove particular String from String url

Tags: java, android

I have to remove this.

```java
String removeKey = "problem_keys";
```

**Code**

```java
public class Solution {
    
public static void main(String args[]) {
    
        String removeKey = "problem_keys";
        String url = "{\"arrival_mode:Self Drop;schedule:2020-09-10;payment_mode:Pay Online;address_id:67052;problem_id:11;problem_name:Abnormal noise;first:2000;product_name:demo tc;category_name:selfby;brand_name:bpl;transaction_type:Request;type:Display;problem_keys:1,35,3,4,5,6,7,15,16,11,12,16;\";}";
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(url);
        removeKey(sb, removeKey);
        System.out.println(sb.toString());
    }

    public static void removeKey(StringBuffer url, String removeKey) {
        int sIndex = url.indexOf(removeKey);
        while (url.charAt(sIndex) != ';') {
            url.deleteCharAt(sIndex);
        }
        url.deleteCharAt(sIndex);
    }
}
```

Expected output.

```
{"arrival_mode:Self Drop;schedule:2020-09-10;payment_mode:Pay Online;address_id:67052;problem_id:11;problem_name:Abnormal noise;first:2000;product_name:demo tc;category_name:selfby;brand_name:bpl;transaction_type:Request;type:Display;}";
```

Comment: what is output expectation?

Comment: I want to remove problem_key: to ; in string url. url is coming dynamically not fix position and length. My code is working fine but i want to short trick of this problem.

Comment: @Er.PremSinghdaksha your code is correctly working according to your output. So, what you actually telling us to do?

Answer (score 1):

Guessing you want also to remove the "values", using java 8:

```
 String toRemove = Arrays.stream(url.split(";")).filter(part -> part.contains(removeKey)).findFirst().orElse("");
 String newUrl = url.replace(toRemove, "");
 System.out.println(newUrl);
```

Speaking about the delimeters you can consider adding ";" to the toRemove string in a conditional block.

If you're aim is only to get rid of the string removeKey you can just:

```
url.replace(removeKey, "");
```

Comment: not working your code our my expectations. I want to remove problem_key: to ; yet from my url.url is coming dynamically not fix problem_key position and length.

Comment: My code doesn't expect your url being the same length or have problem_key in the same position, it works even if there isn't a problem_key string, i compiled and executed my code before posting, I can assure you it works, and I don't see problems with different lengths or parameters positions

Comment: What my code does:
It uses ";" as delimeter in order to obtain a stream of String, every element of a string is eg. ""arrival_mode:Self Drop" , ""arrival_mode:Self Drop;" ecc ...
It filters the stream and find the problem key part, and then it removes that part from the initial string

Answer (score 0):

I would go with this:

```
String removeKey = "problem_keys;";
url = url.replace(removeKey, "") // Replace the whole "problem_keys;" string with an empty string
```

Comment: you don't understand my problem my problem is to remove problem_keys:1,35,3,4,5,6,7,15,16,11,12,16;  this is dynamic String url problem_keys value is length is not fix. Complete url come with in object String form position is not fix so anywhere problem_key: ............to  ;  remove this.